# How to mock and unit test javax.persistence.EntityManager and javax.persistence.Query? Getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, entitymanager

While testing a method. I have come across entity manager to which I need to pass a query.

```
StringBuilder jpqlQuery=new StringBuilder("select Distinct s.modelCode from Model s where 1=1");
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlQuery.toString());
    if(myModel != null ) {      
        jpqlQuery.append(" and s.name = :name");
}
if(myModel != null){
    query.setParameter("name", myModel.getFirstName());
}
```

I am able to enter the jpqlquery.append condition but not able to get inside query.setParameter.

I get NullPointerException at
`Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlQuery.toString());`

Below is my test method:

```
@Test
public void testGetModelNameDetails() {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ModelDTO myModel = Mockito.mock(ModelDTO.class);
    StringBuilder jpqlQuery = new StringBuilder("select Distinct s.modelCode from Model s where 1=1");
    when(myModel.getFirstName()).thenReturn("Downtown");
    when(em.createQuery(jpqlQuery.toString())).thenReturn(query);
    when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(results);
    serviceImpl.getNameDetails(myModel);
}
```

At line `when(em.createQuery(jpqlQuery.toString())).thenReturn(query);` while debugging I can see that the query object is mocked query object.
But inside the method being tested i.e.
at this line: `Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlQuery.toString());` the query object is null.

Hence I get NullPointerException at  `query.setParameter("name", myModel.getFirstName());`

At the start of the Test class I am mocking entityManager and query
@Mock
EntityManager entityManager;

```
@Mock
Query query;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    entityManager = Mockito.mock(em.class);
    query = Mockito.mock(Query.class);
}
```

What am I missing here or doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that both strings are equal? In your method you append something to the string after you created the query out of the string, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, both the strings are equal. If it suits you can ignore the append method. The error occurs without it as well. The problem is: At line `when(em.createQuery(jpqlQuery.toString())).thenReturn(query);` while debugging I can see that the query object is mocked query object. But inside the method being tested i.e. at this line: `Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlQuery.toString());` the query object is null.

And the mocked object of entityManager reached inside the method being tested.

Comment: Have you already tried with:  when(em.createQuery(Mockito.eq(jpqlQuery.toString()))).thenReturn(query); ?

Comment: Yes, same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
when(entityManager.createQuery(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(query);

Comment: Be careful to use anyString, it does any check about the value of the argument the method receives. It is just a string class type check. This means if some changes triggers the if statement and then "jpqlQuery.append(" and s.name = :name")", it keeps matching and it returns the mocked value.